# UpgradeData.php Insert and Delete not working on Magento Cloud

Tags: database, magento2.2, cloud

I wrote a section in UpgradeData.php to insert and delete some values in tables `directory_country_region_name` and `directory_country_region`.  Code below,

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "1.0.6", "<")) {
    $connection = $setup->getConnection();
    $disallowed = implode(',',[6,7,8,9,10,11,17,30,50]);
    $caFrLocalization = array(array('fr_CA',66,'Alberta'),
        array('fr_CA',67,'Colombie-Britannique'),
        array('fr_CA',68,'Manitoba'),
        array('fr_CA',69,'Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador'),
        array('fr_CA',70,'Nouveau-Brunswick'),
        array('fr_CA',71,'Nouvelle-Écosse'),
        array('fr_CA',72,'Territoires du Nord-Ouest'),
        array('fr_CA',73,'Nunavut'),
        array('fr_CA',74,'Ontario'),
        array('fr_CA',75,'Île-du-Prince-Édouard'),
        array('fr_CA',76,'Québec'),
        array('fr_CA',77,'Saskatchewan'),
        array('fr_CA',78,'Yukon'));

    // Add Canadian localized regions
    $connection->insertArray($connection->getTableName('directory_country_region_name'),array('locale', 'region_id', 'name'),$caFrLocalization);

    // Remove extra US states
    $connection->delete($connection->getTableName('directory_country_region_name'),['region_id IN (?)'=>$disallowed]);
    $connection->delete($connection->getTableName('directory_country_region'),['region_id IN (?)'=>$disallowed]);
}
```

And `module.xml`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Project_Ecommerce" setup_version="1.0.7"/>
</config>
```

When I deploy this to the local Magento environment the changes are made as expected.

However when I deploy to the Magento Cloud I do not see the results of this code executing.

---

This is the script I use to deploy these changes to Magento Local,

```
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_CA fr_CA -f
php bin/magento weltpixel:less:generate
php bin/magento cache:flush
sudo chmod 777 var/cache
```

On the Magento Cloud I just deploy the changes with a `git push`.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the version compare to the following:

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "1.0.7", "<")) {
```

It's because the current version is 1.0.6, in your original version compare, it return false result so your script do not run.

**!!BUT!!**

Check the record on table `setup_module` before you apply the fix. If the record show the version is 1.0.7 already, you have to either

- Change the module version to 1.0.8

OR

- Run SQL to change it back to 1.0.6, then rerun `setup:upgrade`

Comment: I changed the version in `version_compare` to 1.0.7 and the version in `setup_module` to 1.0.6 and I can see the code executed during deployment on the cloud,  thanks!  Only the two delete calls did not execute which I assume is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "2.0.2", "<")) {
   $connection = $setup->getConnection();

   $ukLocalization = array(array('GB','IF,'Berkshire'));

   // Add UK localized regions
   $connection->insertArray($connection->getTableName('directory_country_region'),array('country_id', 'code', 'default_name'),$ukLocalization);
}
```